# Global variables and appending for use in other top level functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create an "Admin" section to a small program that executes some maths.

The admin button on the main TK window creates a top level window with an entry field that only turns on when the correct password is entered into a password field (or at least it will be when I figure out how to do this.)

The submit button is intended to update the global variable of a price that will then be remembered by the program from the entry field that would have the new price input by the user. The issue I'm having is how to make the global variable update and change and stay changed once this button is pressed.

This code is only designed to test the ability to do this but for the sake of context I will post it here anyways. Any help towards this goal would be fantastic.

**The issue is that this code does not work, it wont allow me to alter the global variables, and produces the error the variable int has no attribute append?**

**Further - So append was the wrong move, fair enough, the problem i have is that global12mmprice = 200 is not updating the globalvariable and at other points in the program it is still referencing the original value. Is there a way to completely update the global variable so that the program will reflect the new value and the old one will no longer exist?**

```
global12mmprice = 86.67
global15mmprice = 191.19
int12mmprice = int(global12mmprice)
int15mmprice = int(global15mmprice)


class mainwindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Glass Table", command = self.glsqWindow)
        b1.grid(column=1,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text='Round Table', command = self.glrnWindow)
        b2.grid(column=2,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0
        b3 = tk.Button(self, text='Console Table', command = self.glcnWindow)
        b3.grid(column=3,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0
        b4 = tk.Button(self, text='Admin', command = self.admin)
        b4.grid(column=4,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0


    def admin(self):       
        self.count += 1
        window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        window.geometry("600x350+300+300")

        def submit():
            int12mmprice.append(200)


        b1 = tk.Button(window,text='Submit', command=submit)
        b1.grid(column=3,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
```

There is alot more code after this but this is the relevant part. Also any general advice you might have is of course welcome.

**ANSWER:- Provided with alot of assistance from "fdhsdrg". This is the solution that i implemented to get the desired result for anyone who has this question in future.**

As was explained to me i needed to create a file that the program could read and write to that would create the necessary information for the program to access and alter as and when needed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import pickle, os

file=open('prices.dat','rb')
data=pickle.load(file)
file.close
global12mmprice = data[0]
global15mmprice = data[1]

class mainwindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Glass Table", command = self.glsqWindow)
        b1.grid(column=1,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text='Round Table', command = self.glrnWindow)
        b2.grid(column=2,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0
        b3 = tk.Button(self, text='Console Table', command = self.glcnWindow)
        b3.grid(column=3,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0
        b4 = tk.Button(self, text='Admin', command = self.admin)
        b4.grid(column=4,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
        self.count = 0


    def admin(self):       
        self.count += 1
        window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        window.geometry("600x350+300+300")



        def submit():
            global data
            data[0] = '86.67'
            file=open('prices.dat','wb')
            pickle.dump(data,file)
            file.close        
            global root
            box.showinfo('Administration','The program will now terminate and the prices                   will be updated.')
            root.destroy()
        b1 = tk.Button(window,text='Submit', command=submit)
        b1.grid(column=3,row=2,pady=50,padx=10)
```

As you can see the data list in the .dat file gets updated, later i will replace this with a get.entry() field but for now this demonstrates the intended design. You might want to consider using resetboard instead of destroy if you want the program to automatically relaunch after closing.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How can i append global variables permanently in a program. The code above does not work.

Comment: @LMCT edit the question to include it.

Comment: Done apologies for the blatent oversight

Comment: Easy on the imports man, you really don't need the second and third line in this code. Importing tkinter using `import tkinter as tk` is enough. Furthermore you could think about opening a file using `with open('prices.dat','rb') as file:`. This makes sure files will be closed, even if an error occurs before closing (see the last part of 7.2.1 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)) . Apart from that I think you're getting pretty close to where you want to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message you added pretty much explains everything.
int12mmprice is an Integer, which does not have the method append. Append is a method which can be used on objects of type List:

```
>>> a=9
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a.append(15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    a.append(15)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

>>> a=[9]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> a.append(15)
>>> a
[9, 15]
```

EDIT:

Right, now the problem of the scopes. To edit the global int12mmprice put `global int12mmprice` at the start of the `submit` function. This makes sure that `submit` does not look at int12mmprice in its own function scope but in the global scope.

Comment: hi, thanks for the input, unfortunately it cant be a list, it needs to be just a single number, double,float or integer that i can convert to float for math usage. I dont want to add a price to the list i want to change the price entirely. Maybe the correct function is not "append" but i am at a loss on how to do it.

Comment: Right, then append indeed isn't what you need. To change the value of int12mmprice simply use `int12mmprice=200`

Comment: seems simple enough, but after having changed my code to reflect it and added prints to see the value at different points in the program, upon pressing submit, the value is updated, but when i go back to the other toplevel window, the variable has re-acquired its original figure. Any ideas or would you like me to post the whole program?

Comment: Ah I see. I have edited my answer, this should work.

Comment: Okay buddy, your clearly a dab hand at this, so hopefully you can see me through to a conclusion. After having enacted your suggestion, it does indeed work. However, and you knew this would happen really :P is that when i close the program and re-open it, it re-acquires the original prices, i really need it to be a permanent change.

Comment: Well, that would mean you have to save it to the hard drive somewhere and read it when opening the program. How to do this depends on what you want your file to look like. Do you want to include the variable name or not? Do you need to save multiple variables? More info on writing and reading files can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: So the intended use of this will be once its completed to create a build list i believe its called with an MSI installer to be installed on a server so that it can be accessed using multiple remote logins, so i suppose that it will be fine to have a file that denotes the price values. I dont know how to do this but i suppose that is a little off topic from the original answer, but i would like to ask you if it is better save it a string format on a txt doc or a binary format to be read?

Comment: To be honest i have no experience with any of that and if you do have any more questions on this, i would propose to ask a new question for that. But if writing to a file is fine with you I'd recommend using that since it's very easy.  As far as the saving format goes, I really don't see any advantage in saving in binary format. Just save a string like `'int12mmprice = '+str(int12mmprice)`.

Comment: Okay i will do some learning on that, thanks very much youve been a great help, id upvote you but apparently ive not been voted on enough to have an opinion! take care dude